# Can't find File Templates with Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, file-templates

In previous versions of Android Studio I always used it to get file templates to cut down the time for writing code. But now with the latest version (Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2) I can't find the file templates?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what I found is that the **problem is not with this version of Android Studio specifically**. But it **happens when you update Android Studio** as it unfortunately deletes the previously created file templates. So **be careful when updating Android Studio and take a copy of your template files**.

i found android studio file templates in:

*Windows ::*
C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\fileTemplates

*MacOs ::*
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/settingsRepository/repository/templates